# Maple code to Latex file

Tags: maple

I am writing a project in Latex and have been using Maple to help calculate various things. I want to copy the code in maple and put it into the Latex file so it will still maintain the maple style and layout. [image] This is the code I am aiming to show via Latex. I have tried various different google search codes to no avail. These include the help shown on here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109200/how-to-include-maple-code-in-latex and that shown via the maplesoft help

Comment: Does [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+maple+to+latex) help?

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68060/insert-maple-algorithm-to-latex) help, too? :)

Comment: Ive tried that MattAllegro and it wouldnt work, any other ideas?